# How to animate an 45 degree object to a curve?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, path

I want to animate different walls to follow a curve and deform along the curve.
For object with a perfect 90 Degree to a path, it works.
[image]

But if I do the same with an object, that has an oblique wall, the object animation to curve doesnt work anymore. It does strange things. Is there a special trick here that makes the effect look like my straight wall animation?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am happy for any help.

Greetings, Sascha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Apply Rotation** to *Object* and *Curve* and animate along X axis

Comment: I think it isnt the same animation technique which I used.
How can I share my blender file here? via link to googleDrive?

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/ copy paste given link to your Q via Edit.

Comment: thanks for the link.
The 2 other animation shows how i want it. The wall with the 45 degree angle at both end doesnt work with that technique. Maybe you know the alternatives.

Blender-file here:
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=por1n59W" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/por1n59W/)

Comment: Any reason to have object rotated 45 deg?  ... **Apply Rotation** to Object and Curve and animate along X axis ... I asked you to place link into your original question (not into comment section) so please next tine :) thank you keep this site organised.

Comment: Thank you sou much for the answer, the issue was really the Apply to Rotation to both (Object and Curve). Sorry, for the wrong formating of my blender file. I keep it in mind for the future. Again. Thank you!

Comment: Great it helped :)